# Dead link in "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center, editing-help

The page that describes the formatting of the posts: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/formatting contains the dead link for Google Prettify.

The dead link is: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Since google prettify has moved to Github, the new link should be:
https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I've fixed this and it should be right now.